# Check uniqueness when create virtual network in Azure marketplace UI

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm developing an application in the **Azure marketplace**. This is an ARM template based application which contains **createUiDefinition.json** file and **mainTemplate.json** file.

In front-end UI file, I need to let user select or create the storage account and the virtual network. If a user creates a new storage account, [StorageAccountSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/microsoft-storage-storageaccountselector) will help to check the storage account name uniqueness in the front-end automatically, however, the [VirtualNetworkCombo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/microsoft-network-virtualnetworkcombo) will not do that.

So is there any way that make sure user created new virtual network name is unique? Thanks.